# `Regexp.last_match` call in lambda is `nil` when lambda is defined in another method

Tags: ruby, regex, lambda

I am using a lambda within the replace argument of a `gsub!`. When lambda is defined in a different method, `Regexp.last_match` or `$~` is empty, going against the expected behaviour of lambda evaluating the expressions at the invocation time. If I run this code, I will get an error, but if I uncomment the first line in transcribe, and it will work.

```
class Test
  def initialize
    @@replace = lambda { "#{callback('*', Regexp.last_match)}" }
  end

  def transcribe(s)
    #@@replace = lambda { "#{callback('*', Regexp.last_match)}" }
    s.gsub!( /(?<l>.?)[aeiou](?<r>.?)/ ) do
      $~[:l] + (@@replace).call + $~[:r]
    end
    s
  end

  def callback( replace, match )
    raise "Error: Match is empty" if match.nil?
    return replace.upcase
  end
end

t = Test.new
puts t.transcribe('example')
```

Can anybody tell me if I am doing something wrong, or it is a bug?

I've googled it: [ruby Regexp.last_match lambda](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&spell=1&q=ruby%20Regexp.last_match%20lambda), and it seems there is a bug with `$1` in a different situation, but I cannot understand if it would be related to this one.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression global variables (`Regexp.last_match` is just an accessor for $~) aren't really global at all. From the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match) for `last_match`

> Note that the last_match is local to the thread 
>   and method scope of the method that did the 
>   pattern match.

So when your lambda is defined in a different method, the method scope is different  and so its accessing its own private Regexp.last_match, which isn't set. The easiest thing is probably to pass `Regexp.last_match` as an argument to your lambda

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the match as a parameter to the block

```
s.gsub!( /(?<l>.?)[aeiou](?<r>.?)/ ) do |match|
  $~[:l] + (@@replace).call(match) + $~[:r]
end
```

this should fix your issue.

In general, I would not use magic like `$~` unless it is on the same line as the regular expression. It keeps the code more readable.